# checking if an URL matching with a pattern

Tags: php, url, design-patterns

i have a code to get a list of pattern from a website: https://noembed.com/providers

with the following code, i can display all the patterns:

```
$supported = 'https://noembed.com/providers' ;
$jsonSUPP = json_decode(file_get_contents($supported),true) ;
echo 'pour:'.$url.'<br/>'  ;
foreach ($jsonSUPP as $key => $value) { 
foreach ($value[patterns] as $ent) { 
echo "**patt : $ent <br />\n" ;
}
}
```

now i would like to create a condition: if $url is matching with $ent then ...
i tried with `preg_match` but i have an error. and ereg too

could you help me please

Comment: Ah yes, the wonderful "I have error", and then not mentioning what the error actually is. Did you code explode? Did it make your PC melt down? Did an alien construction company demolish the planet moments before your pc was about to report results?

Comment: What error do you have with preg_match? would you post your regex? And don't use ereg* family, it's deprecated

Comment: before telling all my life, i prefer to see if someone read me, and then i post the error if someone ask me. a lot of time ppl dont reply to a question so ... my error was "Warning: preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash" . thanks @damien for the friendly reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and use preg_quote so to escape slashes in the url:

```
if(preg_match('/' . preg_quote($url) . '/', $ent))
   return true;
```

Or change delimiter:

```
if(preg_match('%' . $url . '%', $ent))
   return true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the regexps with delimiters - I've use `(` and `)` below:

```
<?php

$url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error";

$supported = 'https://noembed.com/providers' ;
$jsonSUPP = json_decode(file_get_contents($supported),true) ;
echo 'pour:'.$url."<br/>\n"  ;
$match = NULL;
foreach ($jsonSUPP as $key => $value) { 
    foreach ($value['patterns'] as $ent) { 
        if (preg_match("(".$ent.")",$url)) {
            $match = $key;
            break;
        }
        //echo "**patt : $ent <br />\n" ;
    }
    if ($match !== NULL) {
        break;
    }
}
if ($match) {
    echo "$url matched $match ({$jsonSUPP[$match]['name']}): \n";
    print_r($jsonSUPP[$match]);
}
```

Output:

```
pour:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error<br/> 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error matched 3 (Wikipedia): 
Array  (
  [patterns] => Array
     (
         [0] => http://[^\.]+\.wikipedia\.org/wiki/.*
     )

  [name] => Wikipedia 
)
```

Comment: It's the key from the big array in `$jsonSUPP` for the matching entry.